# Add subelement to JSON array

Tags: arrays, json, nested, element

I have the following code where I design the format of a JSON-array dynamically from variables ==>

```
            var Title = '"text_title"'
            var Topic2 = '"text_topic2"'

            var jsonData = [ ];

            createWantedJSON("title", data[i].topic, jsonData)
            function createWantedJSON(title, Topic2, arr) {
                arr.push({
                    "Topic": title,
                    [Topic2] : {
                        "Topic3": [{
                            "Subitem1": "Text1",
                            "Subitem2": "Text2",
                            "Subitem3": "Text3"
                        }]
                    }
                }
```

This goes fine for the key and value which are not nested. But I don't know how to make it dynamic for the content of Topic3. I tried making a variable with the following content =>

`'"Subitem1": "Text1", "Subitem2": "Text2", "Subitem3": "Text3"'` but then of course it sees the content as one string and not as elements of the nested Topic3 array. I guess this isn't that hard but I can't seem to fix it.

Comment: Please, at the very least, post code samples that do not contain syntax errors. And there is no JSON in your question either. You talk about regular JS objects and arrays.

Comment: Tomalak; sorry I completed the code and produced valid JSON as you advised. Do you know how I can add subelements (key-value) to the "Topic3" (sub)object? Thank you!